# Access VBA: The Command or Action 'SaveRecord' isn't available now

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access form I have a `Save` button that executes the following command:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

sometimes it happens that I get the error:

```
The Command or Action 'SaveRecord' isn't available now
```

I actually don't know why. In these cases, I use to close and reopen the Access file a couple of times and then it works.

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

**UPDATE**

Well, now I have the same problem with the `Copy` command:

```
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste
```

The same error message:

```
The Command or Action 'Copy' isn't available now
```

Comment: This usually happens if a record is unchanged, or locked by another user. Can one of those be the case?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth well, the DB is not shared so I am the only user that is working on it. The only "interface" with that DB is the form that I am using. So it should be locked for that reason. The "funny" thing is that now I am having the same error with `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy` ufffffff